# Regular expression for URL that starts with domain name

Tags: c#, .net

We need to check whether URL is exist or not in the text.We have almost completed all the possibilities.Need to know about a regex if an URL start with domain name

like

> Testing the url   google.com.

Output should be google.com.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This regex matches all words with inner dots:

```
\w+([.]\w+)+
```

So, for example, it would find `"google.com"` in `"Testing the url google.com."`.

Is this what you're looking for?